# Find By Full Name Or Email in Find Method Generic Repository?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

I Want Use Full Name Or Email Instead Of Id For Search in Find Method in Generic Repsoitory ?
How Can Search With FullName in Find Method Instead Of Id?
This is FindById Method

```
    public async Task<T> GetByIdAsync(object Id)
    {
        return await _dbContext.Set<T>().FindAsync(Id);
    }
```

I Want Search In Code Above  With Full Name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a generic function to your repository, like this:

```
public T FindBy(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate)
{
    return Context.Set<T>().Where(predicate).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

And then in your program, call it like this:

```
var person1 = MyGenericRepository.FindBy(r => r.FullName == "John Smith");
var person2 = MyGenericRepository.FindBy(r => r.Email == "jane.smith@gmail.com");
```

Assuming you have FullName and Email in your DB Set.